# Javascript local storage not working with drop menu populated from mysql

Tags: javascript, php

I wont to keep the selected item of my menu after reload or in a different page with the samedrop menu.
This code works perfectly but i need to populate mi dropdownmenu with mysql.

```js
document.getElementById("plist").onchange = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('plist', document.getElementById("plist").value);
}
if (localStorage.getItem('plist')) {
    document.getElementById("plist").options[localStorage.getItem('plist')].selected = true;
}
```

```html
<select name="produttore" id="plist">
    <option value="0">Audi</option>
    <option value="1">BMW</option>
    <option value="2">Alfa Romeo</option>
    <option value="3">Aborth</option>
</select>
```

If i populate the menu with that code the local storage doesn't seem to work.

```js
document.getElementById("plist").onchange = function() {
    localStorage.setItem('plist', document.getElementById("plist").value);
}
if (localStorage.getItem('plist')) {
    document.getElementById("plist").options[localStorage.getItem('plist')].selected = true;
}
```

```html
<select name="produttore" id="plist">
<option value=" ">Seleziona produttore</option>
<?php
foreach($results as $produttore) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $produttore["category_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $produttore["name"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

KEEP CALM AND don't kill me I'm a noob

Comment: Make sure the "value" properties are populated with the correct values. Also, make sure the js code that selects the item based on localstorage runs after the element is drawn on page and the option that you want selected actually exists.

Comment: "value" is popolated with the primary_key of my table so is populated with an integer number, the js code I've tryed to put it in the head and also before i close the body but no positive result. I'm open to other solution, this code will be moved into opencart, PHP SESSION could be a solution but i have no experience with that.

Answer (score 0):

As miraco suggested the problem was the value.
I changed my code and using "selectedIndex" and not "value" it work.